# Create CSE array formulain Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

---

In the cell A1 of my Excel sheet named 'Sheet2' has the following formula (CSE Array Formula)

```
{=INDEX(Data1, MATCH(F26&G26,Data2&Data3,0),7)}
Data1 = Sheet1!$D$3:$J$604
Data2 = Sheet1!$D$3:$D$604
Data3 = Sheet1!$D$3:$E604
```

I want to rewrite this in VBA Macro, and the below is what I have tried so far (Yes, it is giving me an error (ERROR: Can't assign to array)

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim var1(1 To 10) As Integer
Dim var2(1 To 10) As Integer

With Application.WorksheetFunction
   var1 = .Match((F26 And G26), (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D604") And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E604")), 0)
   var2 = .Index(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:J604"), var1, 7) 
   Range("A1").Value = var2
End With

End Sub
```

Any suggestion/correction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you defining `var1` and `var2` as arrays?

To concatenate strings, use the same `&` operator as the formula: `(F26 & G26)`
To concatenate ranges, use the `Application.Union()` method: `Application.Union(range1, range2)`

I assume from the function, you want to return an array of all the places in your area that match the values in F26 and G26

This would be my attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Values()
Dim FindData
Dim Counter As Long
Dim DataPoints As Long
Dim ReturnData()
ReDim ReturnData(1)
DataPoints = 1

Values = Application.Union(Range("D3::D604"),Range("E3:E604"))
FindData = Range("F26").Value & Range("G26").Value

For Counter = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
    If findata = (Values(Counter, 1) & Values(Counter, 2)) Then
        ReDim Preserve ReturnData(DataPoints)
        ReturnData(DataPoints) = Counter
        DataPoints = DataPoints + 1
    End If
Next

Range("A1:A" & DataPoints) = ReturnData

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you mean `Application.Union` and not `.Intersect` ?  Intersect will be an empty range in this case.

Comment: There would be only 1 matches, so i don't need RdEim Preserve. or should I need it for saftey purpose?

Comment: if you know there will only be one, then you don't need the `ReDim preserve`, but it's useful to know about, when they come back and give you data with 2 matches :)

Comment: True that, i really appreciate your help Sean.